# v4l2 mpeg-ts stream to http stream on android

Tags: android, http, dvb, dvblast

I am trying to read a v4l2 stream and re-stream via http streaming on android.

First of all I don't have any code but I think this question is about coding and I don't find a better place to post it...

I have tried using mumudvb, tvheadend and dvblast android ports but my v4l2 API is a little bit strange (propietary calls from chipset vendor, I have the appropiate API to call them (similar to v4l2)) but they don't work at all.

The fact is that I don't manage how to make it conceptually, I mean, I suppose that I have to read buffer data from /dev/dvb0.dvr0 device and write it to an tcp socket.

The question is:

When do I need to write http headers?

Has anybody made something like this?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something similar to spydroid, you should start to analize this project for beginning
https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera